# How are domain registrars able to include unlimited DNS and email forwarding?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

DNS services on average cost $30/year for 600,000 queries per month. Email forwarding is about $30/year for 10,000 emails a month.

How can a registrar, whom I pay only $10/year for a domain, be able to host DNS with millions of queries a month and handle over 10,000 forwarding requests a month? Does the registrar posses a legal right to drop services?

Comment: Where did you get these numbers??? Other than saying your information is incorrect (which I'm very tempted to say), I'll say this: Economy of Scale, and the fact that the majority of websites don't have nearly that much traffic.

Comment: Mostly DynDNS and its competitors http://dyn.com/dns/ and http://dyn.com/email/

Comment: DNSMadeEasy (considered a cheap provider) wholesales $2.40/year for 1 million queries per month; that is if you purchase 1 billion queries. http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/managed-dns-hosting/

Comment: Amazon Route 53 hosts DNS for $0.50/month and 1 million queries per month for $0.50

Comment: @Rex, if my site has 10 million queries a month, that's $60 a year. How can my domain registrar, who makes ~$2 on a domain sale, afford that?

Comment: 99% of their customers only get hundreds or thousands of DNS queries a month.

Comment: Not to mention they make money on the domains, hosting, design, certificates, email, etc. DNS is a simple service, and I am almost certain they come out ahead in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the nature of the DNS traffic changes depending on where the nameserver falls in the delegation chain. Comparing registrars to DDNS providers is sorta like comparing apples to oranges; they're both fruit (authoritative DNS), but they're also different kinds.

- **Registrar**: Many, many domains, but for the most part serving up `NS` delegations and glue records (`A`). These records generally do not have small TTLs. Both of these facts mean that the number of different records requested *per domain* is very small in volume (2-4 records), and individual caching nameservers are not having to request them very often.
- **Auth Nameservers**: Fewer domains than a registrar, but the total # of records per domain increases, and the TTLs will be lower. The traffic will not be very sustained per domain if the TTLs are not set consistently low. Sustained traffic increases as you host more domains (particularly if they're popular), but still shouldn't be very significant as long as caching nameservers are doing their job. It's trivial for individuals with a dedicated connection to host their own DNS; what they lack is the geo-redundant infrastructures of larger companies.
- **DDNS Providers**: They also provide authoritative nameservers, but the nature of their traffic is more specialized. TTLs for individual records will be much smaller on average; they have to be, otherwise it would take caching nameservers a long time to notice when the records change. This means they have higher query rates per domain than standard authoritative nameservers. Additionally, they also receive traffic from the dynamic DNS records change requests (DDNS clients), not just traffic from caching nameservers.

Obviously there's some room for mix and match between these classes of service; it's not uncommon for registrars to offer managed auth DNS. Still, they won't be providing it for *every* domain that they host, so the question is best served by understanding how the nature of the services differ.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! I guess a mixture of low service and a large percentage of clients who do not use much queries justify the service.

Answer (score 1):

Service Level Agreements and quality of service guarantees.

The dedicated DNS providers distinguish themselves from run of the mill DNS providers (the registrars and hosters) by having a reliable infrastructure that's better than the others. By providing a better service, they can charge more.

The cheap/free DNS options can have outages or other interruptions in service, where the dedicated DNS outfits do whatever they can to prevent that from happening. If reliable DNS service is key to your business, then reliability is worth the investment; or so goes their business plan.

Comment: Can a Domain Registrar terminate its service do to a heavy use of included dns service?

Comment: @timofey Depends on the Terms of Service you signed when you signed up, I'm afraid. They all can do that. Whether or not they actually **do** is something I can't answer.

Comment: Hmm... funny thing is that I've never seen registrar's Terms of Service mention anything about dns query limits.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take GoDaddy as an example.  [They say](http://www.godaddy.com/newscenter/about-godaddy.aspx) that they have 55 million domains "under management".

As a very rough approximation, each one of those domains might cost, on average, $10/year.  If that number holds, they'd take in $550 million in registration fees this year.  Of course they have overhead to pay, and I'm pulling that $10/month number out of thin air (as were you), but their domain registration business alone is pretty large.

Then they also sell all sorts of other hosting services, SSL certs, etc.

[BusinessWeek](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2012-05-24/the-challenge-of-classing-up-go-daddy) put their 2011 revenue at $1.14 billion.

They already have to run datacenters to supply their other (paid) hosted services, so DNS hosting and email forwarding do not account for 100% of their infrastructure overhead.  By bandwidth and DC square footage I'd wager it makes up a pretty small segment, and costs them relatively little.  (Relative for them could be a few million dollars per year, of course).

Although I can't find any hard numbers, I'd also believe that most high-traffic sites are not using GoDaddy's free DNS services, and are almost certainly not using their email forwarding.

I'm just making good-faith judgements here, but I'd also think that a large portion of domains registered with them just sit idle, probably with GoDaddy's own parking page (which is pure marketing for them).  This includes domains registered to cover common misspellings, alternate TLDs, etc, as well as those registered by people with the best of intentions to start the next eBay, but never actually get around to writing it.  I can only cite my own list of domains as evidence, of which ~75% fall into one of those categories.

So **relative to their overall size**, GoDaddy really doesn't serve much free DNS or email traffic.  I believe this would hold true for any established registrar, and just differ in scale.

The bottom line is that **you** might pay $10/year and cost your registrar $100/year to provide those services, but for every one of you there's probably thousands of people paying $10/year and costing GoDaddy $0.10/year.